What is happening to my magnolia?
This is their 3rd year being in this spot. They occasionally drop leaves, not very often. All the rest of my magnolias are thriving and flowering but these two are on the struggle bus. What is happening ? They are still green and those little bud looking things grow, which is weird. I am ready to take them out they have been like this for about 4 months know! Any help will be greatly appreciated ! 
